# Error when copy file from one place to another in NSFileManager

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager

When I use NSFileManager to copy one file (directory) from one place to another by using copyItemAtPath, it gives me error.

Here is the code:

```
 [[NSFileManager defaultManager]copyItemAtPath:@"/Users/name/Documents/localhost/websiteDesign/_Software/" toPath:@"/Volumes/NAME/" error:&handleError];
 NSLog(@"%@", [handleError description]);
```

Here is the error:

```
 Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=516 "“_Software” couldn’t be copied to “Volumes”   because an item with the same name already exists." UserInfo=0x102842d00
 {NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/Users/name/Documents/localhost/websiteDesign/_Software/, NSUserStringVariant=(Copy), NSDestinationFilePath=/Volumes/NAME/, NSFilePath=/Users/name/Documents/localhost/websiteDesign/_Software/, NSUnderlyingError=0x10283f8e0 "The operation couldn’t be completed. File exists"}
```

However, when I change the name of the destination file which is @"/Volumes/NAME/", to whatever else like @"/Volumes/aaa/", then the error will gone. I do not know why. Thanks !!

Comment: Do you understand the error message? "because an item with the same name already exists"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the full pathname, *including* the actual filename.

[Apple's documentation for `copyItemAtPath:toPath:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/copyItemAtPath%3atoPath%3aerror%3a) states, for the "toPath:" parameter:

> The path at which to place the copy of srcPath. **This path must
>   include the name of the file or directory in its new location.** This
>   parameter must not be nil.

What you're doing right now is trying to overwrite an entire hard drive (volume) with a file.